# What does it mean "Data-normalized"?

Tags: java, database, hibernate

Question is in post's title. Additional information: Hibernate docs says, that using relational tables inheritance with strategy SINGLE_TABLE , *data is not normalized* or using JOINED strategy, *data is normalized*. What does it mean???

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: I've tagged 'database' to attract answers. Perhaps consider removing 'java'?

Comment: hibernate relates with java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you map an inheritance relationship into relational database, you have to decide whether each subclass has its own table or there is one single table for the whole class hierarchy where the fields of all subclasses are added up as columns.

Comment: So, what did you said it describes strategies types. What about data-normalization? When I use strategy like SINGLE_TABLE, so all sub-class columns goes in one table. When use JOINED - super class (usually abstract class) id goes to sub-classes tables as foreign key. So what does it have in common with normalization? It simply means if I have a huge table (which can be splitted into few tables) it is not efficient and calls "data not normalized"???

Comment: When you have, say, 1 abstract base object and 100 subclasses with disjunct fields and store them in one single table, you have a massive overhead of nullable columns, because every subclass brings its own columns to the party the other subclasses don't know about - non-normalized means here, that you have a lot of duplication (and null) in the table.

Comment: Accept for a nice explanation in comment